# Move content from field to field collection

Tags: 7, entities

I'm working on a site where a current content type has six image fields, six title fields & six content fields. One field from each (one image, one title & one content) all make up one group, so in total there are six groups of these.

Is it possible to move these into a field collection? I just think it'd be tidier, make more sense & make it easier to maintain.

Also if this is possible, not only how do I do it but is it even wise to move content from a 'normal' field to a field collection like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 3 step

1. In your content type, creat new field collection
2. Write one module, use function [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7). In this function, you can copy data from old fields to new field collections.
3. Go to page admin/content. Select your content type. Select all node. In tab **UPDATE OPTIONS** chose **Publish selected content** and submit. This action to do run code your module write in step 2.